# Possible Lossy Conversion error in java from double to int

Tags: java, operators

We already know that the return type of `Math.lang()` function in java is `double`.

```
class Lossy {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int sum;
        sum=Math.pow(2,3);
        System.out.println (sum);
    }
}
```

Now this statement results in possible lossy conversion error because the variable is of type int and `Math.pow()` return a `double` value i.e. `8.0` which is fair enough.

Now look at the code below with some changes.

```
class Lossy {     
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int sum=2;
        sum+=Math.pow(2,3);
        System.out.println (sum);
    }
}
```

Now if we compile this code we don't get an error of possible conversion error, which we should get because we are storing a double value in an `integer` variable. Moreover, when we are printing the value it shows an integer value. Why?

Answer (score 1):

In the first code, you are assigning a double value to a integer variable. since double value needs 8 bytes whereas integer needs only 4 bytes of memory. We cant store a 8 bytes value into a 4 bytes variable. That's why it shows possible loss of conversion error.

```
class Lossy
  {
   public static void main(String args[])
  {
    int sum;
    sum=Math.pow(2,3);   //Assigning double value to a int variable. its an Error
    System.out.println (sum);
 }
 }
```

In the second example you are not simply or directly assigning a value to a integer variable. but you used an add and assign operator(+=), which functions as follows:

**sum+=Math.pow(2,3)** is equal to **sum = sum + Math.pow(2,3);**

When you do like the above one, JVM performs **Automatic Type Conversion(double to int) or Parsing** for the function Math.pow() and it converts the return value of the function to int while compilation. So it works fine. I hope you understand. Thanks!

Comment: But I think implicit conversion from double to int isn't allowed in java.

Comment: Go through the following link for reference:- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-conversion-java-examples/